# AngularJS UI-Router nested 2 way binging

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's my 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZOj2WutQ9Y7cHJF3CjEF?p=preview).

Check these steps to understand the problem:

1. load. Error message is [hi]
2. click "invalid"
3. Error message should be [invalid]
4. Insert '3' in the input box, error should be []
5. click "invalid". **it looks broken**

Is there some configuration missing from 'home.item'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to define controller name in your routing config.

```
$stateProvider.state('home.item', {
    url: '/item',
    templateUrl: 'item.html',
    controller:'mainController'
  }
)
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UFWTeJBkrJliXMkz7l2F?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, maybe my example was wrong but your solution was not what I was looking for. I don't want a new controller for item. I update the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZOj2WutQ9Y7cHJF3CjEF?p=preview), I was missing how to access to parent scope from directive. Thank you.